# HelixToolkit creates transparent material models to hide behind models

Tags: wpf, 3d

When I tried to create a transparent material model using the HelixToolkit,when I rotated the camera, the model obscured the model behind it.

I created a model with a transparent background with text as the Material. Material and BackMaterial set the image as the material of the model. When I rotate the camera, the model will cover the model behind.